# When can aggregate functions be nested in standard SQL?

Tags: language-lawyer, aggregate-functions, window-functions, sql

I know it wasn't allowed in SQL-92. But since then it may have changed, particularly when there's a window applied. Can you explain the changes and give the version (or versions if there were more) in which they were introduced?

### Examples

1. > Is SUM(COUNT(votes.option_id)) OVER() valid syntax per standard SQL:2016 (or earlier)?

This is my [comment](/questions/61715474/why-can-you-nest-aggregate-functions-when-using-a-window-function-in-postgresql#comment122777320_61715474) (unanswered, an probably unlikely to in such an old question) in [Why can you nest aggregate functions when using a window function in PostgreSQL?](/questions/61715474/why-can-you-nest-aggregate-functions-when-using-a-window-function-in-postgresql).

2. The [Calculating Running Total (SQL)](//www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/589cf5f858e80fd080002a91/groups/58dafba93df738a19c000afc) kata at [Codewars](//www.codewars.com) has as its most upvoted solution (using PostgreSQL 13.0, a highly standard compliant engine, so the code is likely to be standard) this one:

```
SELECT
  CREATED_AT::DATE AS DATE,
  COUNT(CREATED_AT) AS COUNT,
  SUM(COUNT(CREATED_AT)) OVER (ORDER BY CREATED_AT::DATE ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)::INT AS TOTAL
FROM
  POSTS
GROUP BY
  CREATED_AT::DATE
```

(Which could be simplified to:

```
SELECT
  created_at::DATE date,
  COUNT(*) COUNT,
  SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY created_at::DATE)::INT total
FROM posts
GROUP BY created_at::DATE
```

I assume the `::`s are a new syntax for casting I didn't know of. And that casting from TIMESTAMP to DATE is now allowed (in SQL-92 it wasn't).)

3. As [this SO answer](/a/62941702/3777717) explains, Oracle Database allows it even without a window, pulling in the `GROUP BY` from context. I don't know if the standard allows it.

Comment: This is about aggregation (COUNT, SUM, MAX etc.) and analytic functions (COUNT, SUM, MAX **OVER** etc.). Aggregation (`COUNT(*)` in your example) happens first. Then, on the results you can apply analytic functions (`SUM OVER` in your example).

Comment: Oracle is an exception. There you can nest two aggregation functions. This is not standard-compliant, and although I am working a lot with Oracle, I never use this.

Comment: The `::` is a cast operator in PostgreSQL. It is not standard-compliant.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, could you elaborate on analytic functions and how they differ from aggregate functions? The document "Information technology — Database languages — SQL —Part 2:Foundation (SQL/Foundation)" (I'm using the [SQL:2011 late draft](//www.wiscorp.com/sql20nn.zip) [linked from Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#SQL_standards_documents)) doesn't even contain the word "analytic".

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion. "Analytic functions" is just another word for "window functions". In the SQL standard they only use the term "window function". I have added an answer still to explain the difference in more detail.

Comment: SQL-2016 _syntax_ can be verified here: https://developer.mimer.com/sql-2016-validator/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already noticed the difference yourself: It's all about the window. `COUNT(*)` without an `OVER` clause for instance is an aggregation function. `COUNT(*)` with an `OVER` clause is a window function.

By using aggregation functions you condense the original rows you get after the `FROM` clause and `WHERE` clause are applied to either the specified group in `GROUP BY` or to one row in the absence of a `GROUP BY` clause.

Window functions, aka analytic functions, are applied afterwards. They don't change the number of result rows, but merely add information by looking at all or some rows (the window) of the selected data.

In

```
SELECT
    options.id,
    options.option_text,
    COUNT(votes.option_id) as vote_count,
    COUNT(votes.option_id) / SUM(COUNT(votes.option_id)) OVER() * 100.0 as vote_percentage
FROM options
LEFT JOIN votes on options.id = votes.option_id
GROUP BY options.id;
```

we first join votes to options and then count the votes per option by aggregating the joined rows down to one result row per option (`GROUP BY options.id`). We count on a non-nullable column in the votes table (`COUNT(votes.option_id)`, so we get a zero count in case there are no votes, because in an outer joined row this column is set to null.

After aggregating all rows and getting thus one row per option we apply a window function (`SUM() OVER`) on this result set. We apply the analytic `SUM` on the vote count (`SUM(COUNT(votes.option_id))` by looking at the whole result set (empty `OVER` clause), thus getting the same total vote count in every row. We use this value for a calculation: option's vote count diveded by total vote count times 100, which is the option's percentage of total votes.

The PostgreSQL query is very similar. We select the number of posts per date (`COUNT(created_at)` is nothing else than a mere `COUNT(*)`) along with a running total of these counts (by using a window that looks at all rows up to the current row).

So, while this looks like we are nesting two aggregate functions, this is not really the case, because `SUM OVER` is not considered an agregation function but an analytic/window function.

Oracle does allow applying an aggregate function directly on another, thus invoking a final aggregation on a previous grouped by aggregation. This allows us to get one result row of, say, the average of sums without having to write a subquery for this. This is not compliant with the SQL standard, however, and very unpopular even among Oracle developers at that.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks! Before I accept, I have the following question about your query: how is `options.option_text` supposed to be selected? I thought you can't select an expression involving a non-grouping column unless it's under an aggregate function.

Comment: No, the SQL standard also allows columns that are functionally dependent on grouped by columns. `options.id` is probably the table's primary key. Thus `options.option_text` is functional dependent on it, because with one `options.id` you find one `options` row and in that row there is exactly one `options.option_text`. Some DBMS support functional dependency detection, others don't.

Comment: Ah, yes, the newer versions indeed do! And, although not stated, as you hint in your comment, the column names suggest that it's likely there to be a sufficient functional dependency. (And I don't know if the practice from several years ago of having constraints only in documentation is still widely followed, negating this feature. But hopefully not, especially given the availability of `NOT ENFORCED` since at least SQL:2011.)